# String Validation Error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript code ,

```
$(".onlyname").keypress(function (evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :       ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
        (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    });
```

It accepts only string values but it restrict the space key .How do I exclude space key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the condition to exclude the space from the code that stops the event. Space has the code 32, so just change the lower boundary from 32 to 33:

```
if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
  (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
```